# How can I put space between flexbox elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was wondering if there was a way I could have two divs/spans in the same column and have an adequate space in between.

End goal:

[image]

What I currently have:

[image: Current Progress without Text Count]

With Text Count:

[image: With Text Count]

HTML:

```
 <div class="emoji-text-container">
        <textarea type="text" class="text-area form-control" maxlength="279" formControlName="twitterText">
        </textarea>
        <button #toggleEmojiTwitter class="emoji-button mt-2 mr-2" type="button" (click)="_isTwitterEmojiPickerVisible = !_isTwitterEmojiPickerVisible"><mdb-icon class="emoji-icon" far icon="smile"></mdb-icon></button>
        <span class="text-count" [hidden]="_isTwitterEmojiPickerVisible">
          <span>{{_twitterCharLimit - this._postsForm.get('twitterText').value.length}}</span>
        </span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
//Emoji and Text Count

.emoji-container,
.emoji-text-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #d9d7d8;
}

.text-area {
  min-height: 15rem;
  border: 0;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.emoji-button {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
}

.emoji-icon {
  color: #9a9696;
}

.text-count {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #f4f2f2;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 12%;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8e8d8d;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest setup will be to wrap your smiley and count elements in additional flex wrapper, like so:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.textarea {
   height: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="smile"></div>
    <div class="text">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was the most best and simplest answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex for the same, first group those two buttons like

```
<div class="btnGp">
 <button #toggleEmojiTwitter class="emoji-button mt-2 mr-2" type="button" (click)="_isTwitterEmojiPickerVisible = !_isTwitterEmojiPickerVisible"><mdb-icon class="emoji-icon" far icon="smile"></mdb-icon></button>
        <span class="text-count" [hidden]="_isTwitterEmojiPickerVisible">
          <span>{{_twitterCharLimit - this._postsForm.get('twitterText').value.length}}</span>
        </span>
</div>

.btnGp{
display : flex;
justify-content : space-between;
flex-direction : column;
height : 100%;
}
```

by this way it comes up and down, but it does not go to the bottom, why ? because it has 100% height but cant expand, why it cant expand ? because percentage is the relative quantity and the parent does not have any height so add

```
.emoji-text-container{
 // a size of your choice
}
```

and remove the min height from `text-box` and add height 100% to it

Answer (score 1):

The simple skeleton for your issue would be look like below. Two approaches: 1: flex with position and 2) only flex.

It think you looking for the second one.

#### 1. Flex / position Version

```css
.w {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  min-height:200px;
}

.left {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.right {  
  width:70px;    
}
.icons {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;  
}

.top, .bottom {  
  position:absolute;
}
.top {
  top:0;
}
.bottom {
   bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="right">    
    <div class="icons">
      <div class="top">top</div>    
      <div class="bottom">buttom</div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use flex box and the position top and bottom for the icons.

#### 2. Flex only version

```css
.w {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  min-height:200px;
}

.left {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.right {  
  width:70px;    
}
.icons {
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: gray;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="right">    
    <div class="icons">
      <div class="top">top</div>    
      <div class="bottom">buttom</div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
.emoji-text-container --- `position:relative;`
.text-count --- `position:absolute;`
after this you can move "text count" using bottom:0; right:0;

Comment: I know that, but I would to only use flex box .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).